# Where can I find free made animations?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, video

Is there a website which hosts many free animations that can be used in blender? Many websites confuse each other with models (technically is model, but animated).

For example: https://clara.io/view/19b00b61-6d1b-4f6b-92a1-0c69b9b90a45

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I dunno if there's a lot of shared animations out there.  Maybe there are, haven't looked.

You might find some on [BlendSwap](https://www.blendswap.com/), or ask there if there's a certain one you had in mind.

I know there's mo-cap data you can attach to skeletal deformations.   [CMU Graphics Lab Motion Capture Database](http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/)  Something like that might get you halfway to your goal.

Couldn't say about non-organic objects.  Perhaps if other graphics programs offer them, they can be imported.  That's something you'd have to look up, 'cuz I've never expected someone else to do a scene for me; kinda defeats the purpose.